How to find a excact value from a cell containing NamedRange while upload excel in Java?
I am working on importing a data from a Excel Sheet when a user tries to upload (.xlsx) file. For one particular field Field1 - 2233 its using a Named Range to get the actual value and not the named range.
NamedRange:
"IF(AND('Sheet 1'!NbFCbag <>"Weight  including baggage",'Sheet 1'!NbCCbag <> "Weight  including baggage"),('Sheet 1'!NbFC*'Sheet 1'!WFC + 'Sheet 1'!NbFCbag*'Sheet 1'!WFCbag) + ('Sheet 1'!NbCC*'Sheet 1'!WCC + 'Sheet 1'!NbCCbag*'Sheet 1'!WCCbag),IF(AND('Sheet 1'!NbFCbag<>"Weight  including baggage",'Sheet 1'!NbCCbag = "Weight  including baggage"),('Sheet 1'!NbFC*'Sheet 1'!WFC + 'Sheet 1'!NbFCbag*'Sheet 1'!WFCbag) + 'Sheet 1'!NbCC*'Sheet 1'!WCC,IF(AND('Sheet 1'!NbFCbag="Weight  including baggage",'Sheet 1'!NbCCbag <> "Weight  including baggage"),'Sheet 1'!NbFC*'Sheet 1'!WFC + ('Sheet 1'!NbCC*'Sheet 1'!WCC + 'Sheet 1'!NbCCbag*'Sheet 1'!WCCbag),'Sheet 1'!NbFC*'Sheet 1'!WFC+ 'Sheet 1'!NbCC*'Sheet 1'!WCC)))"
`
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

 for (Name namedRange : workbook.getAllNames()) {
                    String rangeName = namedRange.getNameName();
                    try {
                        if (NAMED_RANGE.contains(rangeName)) {
                            AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(namedRange.getRefersToFormula(), workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion());
                            CellReference[] cellReferences = areaReference.getAllReferencedCells();
                            for (CellReference cellReference : cellReferences) {
                                Sheet namedSheet = workbook.getSheet(cellReference.getSheetName());
                                Row row = namedSheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
                                Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
                                if (cell != null) {
                                    namedRangeValues.put(rangeName, getFormulaCellValueAsString(cell,evaluator));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


 private String getFormulaCellValueAsString(Cell cell, FormulaEvaluator evaluator) {
        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
        logger.info("cellValue:");
        switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
            case STRING:
                return cellValue.getStringValue();
            case NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    return cell.getDateCellValue().toString();
                } else {
                    return Double.toString(cellValue.getNumberValue());
                }
            case BOOLEAN:
                return Boolean.toString(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

Error:
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Second part of cell reference expected after sheet name at index 35.
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:579)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:327)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1556)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1514)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1501)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1875)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:2018)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1986)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1943)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.intersectionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1916)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1897)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:2044)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:175)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getFormulaTokens(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:85)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:260)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:205)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:61) at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:109) `   




How do I decode this to get the exact value?

I tried using Formula Evaluator but it fails with the error: Second part of cell reference expected after sheet name at index.


I recall an almost identical question posted recently but I can't find it. I suspect that you posted the other question and then deleted it and posted this one. If that is correct then I don't think you will get a better response by re-posting the exact, same question.

The error is about a reference to for ex. 'Sheet 1'!WFC in a formula. A name WFC is possible using Excel as WFC not violates the rules for names in Excel. But the formula evaluator of Apache POI reads WFC as a column reference to column WFC which exists. Therefore it expects a row number after it. That's why the error Second part of cell reference expected after sheet name at index....  Solution? Someone corrects the programming of the formula evaluator of Apache POI.
